# Faster way to insert data in neo4j?

Tags: neo4j

I am trying to insert  unique nodes and relationship in neo4j.

What I am using :-

- Neo4j Community Edition running on Amazon EC2.[Amazon Linux m3.large]
- Neo4j Java Rest Binding [ https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/java-rest-binding ]

**Data Size and Type :**

TSV File [Multiple]. Each contains more than 8 Million Lines [each line represent a node or a relationship].There are more than 10 files for nodes.[= 2 Million Nodes] and another  2 million relations.

I am using UniqueNodeFactory for inserting nodes. And inserting sequentially, couldn't find any way to insert into batches preserving unique nodes.

The problem is it is taking huge time to insert data. For example it took almost a day for inserting 0.3 million unique nodes. Is there any way to fasten the insertion?

Answer (score 5):

Don't do that.

**Java-REST-Binding was never made for that.**

Use either

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 1000
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "http://some.url" as line
CREATE (u:User {name:line.name})
```

You can also use merge (with constraints), create relationships etc.

See my blog post for an example: http://jexp.de/blog/2014/06/using-load-csv-to-import-git-history-into-neo4j/
Or the Neo4j Manual: http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/cypherdoc-importing-csv-files-with-cypher.html

Comment: USING PERIODIC COMMIT 10000 LOAD CSV FROM 'file:csv-      data/user/1.txt' AS line FIELDTERMINATOR '\t'CREATE (n:user{id:line[0],label:line[1],age:line[2],gender:line[3]})

Is this a valid query for neo4j 2.0.3? I am getting syntax error.

Comment: Another thing what will i use than?

1.Neo4j Embedded Database
2.Java Rest Binding(RestCypherEngine)